# MUI StaticDatePicker Resizing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Im having issues resizing the MUI staticDatePicker component. I know the only way to do it is by resizing the individual sub-components, but I can't find all of them. Here is what I have so far

```
<Field
  as={StaticDatePicker}
  id='booking_date'
  name='booking_date'
  label='Booking Date'
  value={initialValues.booking_date} 
  autoFocus
  sx={{
     "& .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root": {
          width: 256,
     },
     "& .MuiIconButton-root": {
          width: 32,
     },
     "& .MuiTypography-caption": {
          width: 32,
     },
     "& .MuiPickersDay-root": {
          width: 32,
          height: 32
     },
     "& .MuiYearCalendar-root": {
          width: 256
     },                        
     "& .MuiDatePickerToolbar-title": {
          'font-size': '1.7rem'
     },
     "& .css-1hbyad5-MuiTypography-root": {
          'font-size': '0.7rem'
     },
     backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.main
  }}
  onChange={(newValue) => setFieldValue('booking_date', newValue)}/>
```

The code above successfully resizes the individual days selected, the toolBar header, the year dropdown selection, and the calendarHeader. However, the overall width is still 320px instead of the 256px I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are wrapping the `StaticDatePicker` inside the `Field` component. Have you tried simply adding a css `maxWidth` property to your **sx** object on the `Field` component?

For example:

```
...

sx={ {
    maxWidth: '256px',
    "& .MuiPickersCalendarHeader-root": {
         width: 256,
    },

    ...

} }
```